# Zendesk SDK for iOS

Tags: user-interface, swift4.2, zendesk-api

I want to create a custom UI for raising Ticket and sending it to Zendesk using their API and use their API to show the list of Tickets raised.
Can we use Custom UI for raising Ticket and Support UI of Zendesk for listing the raised Tickets?